# Why did pg_dump and restore create differently sized tables?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I copied a postgres table from the production box to our staging box using the following command from the staging box:

```
pg_dump -h p-db -U postgres somedb | psql somedb
```

The job completed just fine, but when I analyzed the size of the tables via `/dt+`, there was a non-trivial difference in size. All the data appears to have transferred well (I did counts on several tables, which were all equal).

For example, the "streets" table on the production database was 1097 MB. The "streets" table on the staging DB right after the transfer was 978 MB.

I thought initially that a `vacuum` hadn't been run on the prod data. So I `vacuum`'d the "streets" table I referenced above. It's size did decrease, but only to 1042 MB ... still not as low as the 978 MB in the staging table.

**My Question:** Why was there a delta between the sizes of the source and destination tables after a successful pg_dump and load?

Important to note: There were no writes or updates to the database during or after this process. I'm using postgres 9.3.

Comment: I would guess that when presented with the data as a nice stream of inserts, Postgres was able to organize it a little better than if it accumulated over time. If it's on a different partition, it's possible your new partition has a different block size. Finally, are they the same versions of Postgres?

Comment: @Schwern, the postgres block sizes are the default 8K. Both are postgres 9.3. I'm on GCE, and they manage disk block size, striping, etc.

Comment: did you run VACUUM or VACUUM FULL? using 'full' claims more space and optimizes better (note the exclusive lock though). Just a guess.

Comment: @Legato That was it! I did a Vacuum not VF because I didn't want the locking. But I found some downtime, tried the VF on that table and it made it the exact same size as the restored table. So, pg_dump -> psql will dump the table as if you had already done a VF on it. Good to know!